# Credentials.acquireTGTFromCache(null, null) returns null using jre 7

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas, java-7

I'm admittedly unfamiliar with the JAAS API, but need to help out with investigation with a problem we encountered while upgrading to jre 7. Apps that used to be able to auto-login using the currently logged on Windows users name stops working. After some poking around, it comes to this line of code.

```
sun.security.krb5.Credentials.Credentials.acquireTGTFromCache(null, null);
```

This returns null when using a jre 7 jvm, but returns the correct crendentials when using jre 6. I wrote a test class in its simplest form and still see the same behavior, so it cannot have been due to the code in our own classes.

```
package test;

import sun.security.krb5.Credentials;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
        final Credentials yaoza = Credentials.acquireTGTFromCache(null, null);
        System.out.println(yaoza);
    }
}
```

Could this be some kind of configuration problems? Any answer or a pointer to the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiousity - can you confirm that when running under JRE 6 or JRE 7 - your app was running "as an administrator" [in an elevated state] or note?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't entirely follow your question. I'm logged in to windows as a non-administrator, and I'm running my test class in Eclipse.

Comment: When you ran eclipse did you right-click on the icon and select "run as administrator" (if you don't know then I presume the answer is no)

Comment: No. I'm running eclipse as a normal non-administrator user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows registry, here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters
```

There apparently should be the following key:

```
allowtgtsessionkey REG_DWORD (1)
```

...according to somebody in this thread:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2343216

As mentioned there, it might have been a bug in JDK6 that this was working in the first place.

Comment: Do I know you from somewhere?